# Does OpenLayers mergenewparams repeatedly hit a WMS server when you change the layer name?

Tags: openlayers, wms, tilecache

Does mergenewparams repeatedly hit a WMS server if you change the layer name?

For example, you call the server with layer 'a' then you use mergewnewparams and call layer 'b', then you use mergewnewparams and call layer 'a' again. Does it cache layer 'a' or request a new layer 'a' ?

I'm actually using a tilecache, but I assume it works the same for either.

Comment: A request is probably made multiple times, but your browser probably caches the image the first time so subsequent requests hit the cache. You could check your browsers network logs to confirm this.